# Cant' send "kill" command to a docker running in IBM Containers service

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I need to execute:

```
cf ic kill -s HUP my-running-haproxy
```

to make ha proxy reload configuration, but I am getting:

```
rpc error: code = 7 desc = permission denied
```

I have all privileges in the account and can execute all other cf ic commands. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Tested this, I'm seeing the same thing, but only for some signals.  SIGKILL, SIGINT, SIGTERM seem to work, the others return the error as you've seen above.  Very odd.

As a temporary workaround, you could try using `cf ic exec -ti {containerid} kill -s SIGHUP 1` (since the primary command inside the container should show up as id 1, or double check with `cf ic exec -ti {containerid} ps -aux` to be sure!)